# Create divs with different classes and append jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery. I would like to develop this HTML structure in jQuery and create these divs and classes dynamically. Can anybody help me?

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="product-image-wrapper">
    <div class="single-products">
      <div class="productinfo text-center">
        <img src="images/home/viralata2.jpg" alt="" />
        <h2>Brutos</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Conheça esse cãozinho</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-overlay">
          <div class="overlay-content">
            <h2>Brutos</h2>
            <p>Vacinado</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Adotar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="choose">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Possível adoção</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var principal = document.createElement("div");
principal.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-4");

var elem1 = document.createElement("div");
elem1.setAttribute("class", "product-image-wrapper");
principal.appendChild(elem1);

var elem2 = document.createElement("div");
elem1.setAttribute("class", "single-products");
elem1.appendChild(elem2);

var elem3 = document.createElement("div");
elem1.setAttribute("class", "productinfo text-center");
elem2.appendChild(elem3);

var elem4 = document.createElement("img");
elem1.setAttribute("img", "images/home/viralata2.jpg");
elem3.appendChild(elem4);

var elem5 = document.createElement("H2");
var txt1 = document.createTextNode("Brutos")
elem5.appendChild(txt1);
elem4.appendChild(elem4);


var elem6 = document.createElement("a");
elem6.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default add-to-cart");
elem6.setAttribute("href", "#");
elem6.appendChild(elem5);

var elem7 = document.createElement("i");
elem7.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-shopping-cart");
var txt2 = document.createTextNode("Conheça esse Cãozinho");
elem7.appendChild(txt2);
elem6.appendChild(elem7);

var elem8 = createElement("div");
elem8.setAttribute("class", "product-overlay");
elem7.appendChild(elem8);

var elem9 = createElement("div");
elem9.setAttribute("class", "overlay-content");
elem8.appendChild(elem9);

var elem10 = createElement("H2");
var txt3 = createTextNode("Brutos");
elem10.appendChild(txt3);

var elem10 = createElement("H2");
var txt3 = createTextNode("Brutos");
elem10.appendChild(txt3);
elem9.appendChild(elem10);

var elem11 = createElement("P");    
var txt4 = createTextNode("Vacinado");
elem11.appendChild(txt4);
elem10.appendChild(elem11);

var elem12 = createElement("a");
elem12.setAttribute("href", "#");
elem12.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-default add-to-cart");
elem11.appendChild(elem12);

var elem13 = createElement("i");
elem13.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-shopping-cart");
var txt5 = createTextNode("Adotar");
elem13.appendChild(txt5);
elem12.appendChild(elem13);


var elem14 = createElement("div");
elem14.setAttribute("class", "choose");
elem13.appendChild(elem14);

var elem15 = createElement("ul");
elem15.setAttribute("class", "nav nav-pills nav-justified");
elem14.appendChild(elem15);

var elem16 = createElement("li");
elem15.appendChild(elem16);

var elem17 = createElement("a");
elem17.setAttribute("href", "#");
elem16.appendChild(elem17);

var elem18 = createElement("i");
elem18.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-plus-square");
elem16.appendChild(elem18);

var txt6 = createTextNode("Possível Adoção");
```

Comment: Please show your tried code?

Comment: Please, look my code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the markup you wanted using jQuery's `.append()` and using jQuery objects to make it pleasing to the eyes: I hope the comments in the code are understandable though.

Here is a sample snippet:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    /*
     * create the parent container
     */
    let $parent = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-sm-4'
    });

    /*
     * create the product image wrapper container
     */
    let $productImgWrapper = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'product-image-wrapper'
    });

    /*
     * create the single products container
     */
    let $singleProducts = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'single-products'
    });

    /*
     * create the product info container
     * and append <img>, <h2>, and <a> with <i> elements
     */
    let $prodInfo = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'productinfo text-center'
    }).append(
        $('<img/>', {
            src: 'images/home/viralata2.jpg',
            alt: ''
        }),
        $('<h2/>', {
            text: 'Brutos'
        }),
        $('<a/>', {
            href: '#',
            'class': 'btn btn-default add-to-cart',
            text: 'Conheça esse cãozinho'
        }).prepend(
            $('<i/>', {
                'class': 'fa fa-shopping-cart'
            })
        )
    );

    /*
     * create the product overlay container
     * and append the overlay-content container with children:
     * <h2>, <p>, and <a> with <i> elements
     */
    let $prodOverlay = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'product-overlay'
    }).append(
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'overlay-content'
        }).append(
            $('<h2/>', {
                text: 'Brutos'
            }),
            $('<p/>', {
                text: 'Vacinado'
            }),
            $('<a/>', {
                href: '#',
                'class': 'btn btn-default add-to-cart',
                text: 'Adotar'
            }).prepend(
                $('<i/>', {
                    'class': 'fa fa-shopping-cart'
                })
            )
        )
    );

    /*
     * create the choose container
     * and append <ul> element with child :
     * <li> with child <a> with <i> elements
     */
    let $choose = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'choose'
    }).append(
        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'nav nav-pills nav-justified'
        }).append(
            $('<li/>').append($('<a/>', {
                href: '#',
                text: 'Possível adoção'
            }).prepend($('<i/>', {
                'class': 'fa fa-plus-square'
            })))
        )
    );

    // append the product info and product overlay container to single products container
    $singleProducts.append($prodInfo, $prodOverlay);
    
    // append the single products and choose container to the product image wrapper container
    $productImgWrapper.append($singleProducts, $choose);
    
    // append the product image wrapper container to the parent container col-sm-4 then
    // finally append the $parent container to the desired location in this case the body element
    $parent.append($productImgWrapper).appendTo('body');
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Initialize Data</button>
```

As you can see I used this method of creating the elements :

`$(element, attributes object)` to make it easier for you to add/change the attributes of that element. The only thing you need to do is to know where to append or what to append on the jquery object you created.

Example scenario : create a `<p>` element with class `.red`, id `#unique` with text `Hello World` so the jQuery Object would look like this :

```
var paragraph = $('<p>', {
    "class" : 'red', // notice class is quoted '"' because class is a reserved word in javascript
    id      : 'unique',
    text    : 'Hellow World'
};
// append this to anywhere in the document to display it
```

You can further read the jQuery docs [**HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for creating DOM elements